# Best glass to reflect visible light (mainly Green)

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, laser, glass

i have a laser source which emits green light underwater (kept collimator under water) and planning to reflect the green laser back to free space(project is to establish air water interface).

I want to know best glass to reflect this source.commercially available glass are very expensive.

So kindly suggest some other idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Best glass to reflect visible light (mainly Green). I want to know best glass to reflect green laser light. Commercially available glass are very expensive. So kindly suggest some other idea.

If cost is the primary concern (and no concern about loss) mix glass paint with acetone-based nail polish remover or purchase a piece of stained glass, place it over a mirror. A bit more expensive is a green mirror.

Since a laser (single frequency) is involved it's possible to use [thin film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-reflective_coating#Interference_coatings) reflection, as a first surface mirror it would be most efficient; also the most expensive solution.